# ArgoCD update error - Unable to continue with update: ServiceAccount "argocd-notifications-controller" in namespace "argocd" exists

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, argocd

When updating ArgoCD via Terraform from version 3.31.1 to version 5.0.0 I got this error:

**Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with update: ServiceAccount "argocd-notifications-controller" in namespace "argocd" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: missing key "meta.helm.sh/release-name": must be set to "argocd"; annotation validation error: missing key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace": must be set to "argocd"**

Have you experienced a similar error?

Thank you.